# GDB not running debug window with send command

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, ctf

```
# Immport library
import sys
from pwn import *

# Read program name from directory
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    prog = sys.argv[1]
else:
    prog=os.path.basename(os.getcwd())

# Define Terminal
context.terminal = ["tmux", "splitw", "-h"]

# Read program as ELF
e = ELF(prog)

payload = b'AAA'

p = gdb.debug([e.path], gdbscript='''
        b *input
        continue
        ''')

# p = process([e.path])

p.send(payload)
print(f'-----------------{payload}') 

# print('Initiating Shell...') 
# p.interactive()

print('Input to close python... \n') 
input()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKb5Q.png)

I'm trying to debug with send command, but it's keep showing this screen, but sendline works. What will be the issue?